# Python : Remove capitalized words from long string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have long string of normal sentences. I want to remove all lines consisting entirely of capitalized words.

So from paragraph:

CHAPTER

Hello hi

1. AAA
2. BBB
3. "CCC"

So what we do is AAA and BBB

I would like to get:

Hello hi So what we do is AAA and BBB

Is there any way, how to do it without splitting the text into list and itereate?

Comment: Try to provide the full path to the file instead of a relative one

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Such an error is unrelated to the file content, right ? in this case, please edit your question to make it as simple as possible, an update the title accordingly. you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve if needed

Comment: I take it the question has changed completely a few times? You needn't split it into a list. The file iterator is lazy, so just iterate over it a line at a time and you wont need to hold the whole thing in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a regular expression like a negative lookahead, i.e. replacing any line that doesn't contain any lower case letters:

```
s = """CHAPTER

Hello hi

    AAA
    BBB
    "CCC"

So what we do is AAA and BBB"""

import re
a = re.sub('^(?:[^a-z]+)$', '', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
print(a)
```

This results in:

```
Hello hi

So what we do is AAA and BBB
```

Comment: @J Gee You're welcome, please remember to mark the correct answer.

Comment: Hey I found another method, using  -> ''.join(f_word for f_word in f if f_word != f_word.upper())